# Devise: Reset token after signing-out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using a single access token and I want to reset it upon signing out.

A possible way would be to call reset_authentication_token! in after_token_authentication in the model, but then I'll have to know that it's a sign_out action in the model.

How can I achieve that in a better way?
I'm using devise 1.3.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override "after_sign_out_path_for" in your application controller and reset your token in there.  No need to write your own SessionController (although it is very simple as Nathan mentioned).

Here's the method you should use: http://rubydoc.info/gems/devise/1.3.4/frames
- (Object) after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)

Method used by sessions controller to sign out a user. You can overwrite it in your ApplicationController to provide a custom hook for a custom scope. Notice that differently from after_sign_in_path_for this method receives a symbol with the scope, and not the resource.

By default is the root_path.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really good [blog post](http://zyphmartin.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise) that I used to add to add/reset tokens.

This is of course just a simple example and the links he calls in the view are to create/destroy the tokens. However, these same paths can be used in your controllers to the same effect.

Comment: Thank but it still does not show how to reset token upon signing out.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the reset_authentication_token! from your controller?

Comment: The sign_out action is part of the Devise::SessionsController which located in the Devise gem, it don't want to hack it.

Comment: It's not difficult to modify the existing Devise controllers without having to rewrite everything. You can copy the original SessionsController methods that you want to change and modify the without affecting anything else. There are a couple of examples here on StackOverflow.

The other option would be to do it through a view. I can't think of a way of accomplishing this in a model, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was having the same problem. This is what i found:

[Devise Wiki: simple token authentication example](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise)

[Devise Wike: simple token authentication links](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example)

In my SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController I overwrote the destroy method (took the one from devise rep and altered it)

```
  def destroy
    token_was_removed = remove_current_users_token_if_json_request

    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

    respond_with resource do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to static_pages_login_path }
      format.json {
        if token_was_removed
          render :status=>200, :json=>{:message => "Logout successful." }
        else
          render :status=>401, :json=>{:message => "Logout failed. Invalid token or some internal server error while saving." }
        end
      }
    end
  end



  def remove_current_users_token_if_json_request
    #remove the users authentication token if user is logged in
    if current_user and request.format.json?
      current_user.authentication_token = nil
      return current_user.save
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```